# Not able to get all the columns using json normalise

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have been trying to get all the records from the below-nested dictionary but not being able to fetch fields like pkey, code.

```
{'instrument': {'instrumentId': 15873, 'instrumentSymbol': 'EXCH-XCBT-CBA', 'instrumentType': 'holiday', 'created': '2020-01-10T06:39:27Z'}, 'mappings': [{'pkey': 40295, 'provider': 'pv', 'system': 'holidays', 'mapping': {'code': 'CBA'}, 'created': '2020-01-10T06:39:28', 'updated': '2020-01-10T06:39:28', 'startDate': '2020-01-10', 'endDate': None}]}

import requests
import json, pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import csv
import urllib

URL = "https://dsv.ihsmvals.com/instruments/v2.0/mappings/instruments/all/provider/pv/system/holidays"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)

print(response)
text = response.read()
json_data = json.loads(text)
df_rest = pd.DataFrame(json_data)
df=pd.json_normalize(json_data,'mappings')
complete_df = pd.concat([df_rest,df],axis=1)
complete_df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

This is how the output looks at the moment missing few relevant fields like pkey, code
[image]

Comment: can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the solution for the entire data:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

f = open("api_data.json", "r")
data = json.load(f)
arr1 = []
arr2 = []
for item in data['mappings']:
    tmp1 = {'instrument': [item['instrument']]}
    tmp2 = {'mappings': [item['mappings'][0]]}
    arr1.append(tmp1)
    arr2.append(tmp2)


df_rest = pd.json_normalize(arr1,'instrument')
df_rest2 = pd.json_normalize(arr2,'mappings')
df=pd.json_normalize(data,'mappings')
complete_df = pd.concat([df_rest, df_rest2], axis=1)
print(complete_df)
```

Comment: df_rest = pd.DataFrame([json_data['instrument']])
KeyError: 'instrument'

Comment: my code is based on your attached json, check if the json_data is a dictionary and if it contains the key

Comment: attached json is sample data

Comment: json_data is basically whatever is there in URL

Comment: i tried printing (json_data) and it is indeed a python dictionary

Comment: so please share more of your json data so issue can be reproduceable

Comment: https://dsv.ihsmvals.com/instruments/v2.0/mappings/instruments/all/provider/pv/system/holidays ....... the entire json is in this link, are you able to open it ? if not i will think of an alternate way

Comment: not able to open it

Comment: https://github.com/atulsanwal22/myspace/tree/main

Comment: you should be able to download it now

Comment: i edited the answer, instead of taking the data from the api i took it from a static file

Comment: Thankyou so much, it worked, if possible can you please help me understand the code

Comment: you need to look into the json struct - when you have items wrapped in [] brackets it means it is a list, and you need to iterate it. i kept the values of each instrument and its mapping in two lists (arr1 and arr2) and after that i executed the pd.json_normalize

Comment: and why we used [0] in tmp2 however not used in tmp1 ?     tmp1 = {'instrument': [item['instrument']]}
    tmp2 = {'mappings': [item['mappings'][0]]}

Comment: the first one is not in a list, the second one is always the first value in the list, look at the json struct